# Finding the limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

If $x_1$ and $y_1$ be positive numbers, $x_{n+1}$ $=$ $1\over 2$$(x_n+y_n)$ and $2\over y_{n+1}$ $=$ $1\over x_n$ $+$ $1\over y_n$ $\forall$ $n$ $\ge$ $1$. Show that the sequences $x_n$ and $y_n$ are monotonic and converge to a common limit $l$ where $l^2$ $=$ $x_1y_1$.

I proved that these two sequences are monotone, bounded and hence convergent. But I can't find that unique limit. I've been trying it with telescopic sum, but it doesn't help at all. 
Also, I failed to establish a good relation between $x_{n+1}$ and $x_n$ or $y_{n+1}$ and $y_n$.

Please help me to find that limit.

Comment: What you describe is the Gauss composition of the arithmetic and harmonic means which turns out to be the geometric mean. The composition of means is treated in detail in the book "PI and the AGM" by the Borwein brothers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As shown in dxiv's answer
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}y_{n+1}
&=\frac{x_n+y_n}2\frac{2x_ny_n}{x_n+y_n}\\
&=x_ny_n\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Therefore, $x_ny_n=x_1y_1$. Additionally,
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}-y_{n+1}
&=\frac{x_n+y_n}2-\frac{2x_ny_n}{x_n+y_n}\\
&=\frac{(x_n-y_n)^2}{2(x_n+y_n)}\\[3pt]
&\in\left[0,\frac{|x_n-y_n|}2\right]\tag{2}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, for $n\gt1$,
$$
0\le x_n-y_n\le\frac{|x_1-y_1|}{2^{n-1}}\tag{3}
$$

Furthermore, it follows from $(2)$, that for $n\gt1$,
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}-x_n
&=\frac{x_n+y_n}2-x_n\\
&=\frac{y_n-x_n}2\\
&\le0\tag{4}
\end{align}
$$
Thus, $x_n$ is decreasing, and by $(1)$, $y_n$ is increasing.

Answer (score 6):

Hint:

$$\require{cancel}
x_{n+1} y_{n+1} = \frac{x_n+y_n}{2}\cdot\frac{2}{\cfrac{1}{x_n}+\cfrac{1}{y_n}}=\frac{\cancel{x_n+y_n}}{\bcancel{2}}\cdot\frac{\bcancel{2} \,x_n y_n}{\cancel{x_n+y_n}} = x_n y_n
$$

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it goes to $x_{n+1}y_{n+1}$ $=$ $x_1y_1$. Now I can apply limit.

Comment: @AnikBhowmick Right. You proved that the limits exist $x_n \to x\,$, $y_n \to y\,$. Then passing the first relation to the limit gives $x=\frac{1}{2}(x+y)\,$, so $x=y=l\,$. Then passing $x_n y_n=x_1y_1$ to the limit gives $l^2=x_1 y_1\,$.